# Switching a logic gate on or off

Tags: boolean-logic, digital-logic

if I have an "AND gate" with three inputs "A,B and control line C"

can I control switching AND gate on or off .. just like this if C == 1 then AND gates works with input A,B if C==0 then nothing happens

can this be done by any method ??

Comment: You're looking for a [tri-state logic gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate#Three-state_logic_gates).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it in pseudo-code(if I understood correctly):

```
    if((c == 1) && (A || B))
```

Forgive me if I've got the wrong end of the stick- logic gates are just a way of making a simple concept confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Achieve the same output from simpler (2-input) AND gates: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, hook a switch to the chip to toggle whether it is powered on or not. You don't need any fancy equipment or doubled gates, just turn the thing on to have it function as normal, turn it off and no matter what inputs you apply you'll get 0v on the output pin.